# what's the semantics of arrange(flights, desc(is.na(x)), x)?

Tags: r

I'm new to R from Python.
When I read the book "R for data science", the function

```
df <- tibble(x = c(5, 2, NA))
arrange(df, desc(is.na(x)), x)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#> x
#> <dbl>
#> 1 NA
#> 2 2
#> 3 5
```

confused me.what's the semantics for this. Can I do this?

```
arrange(df, x > 3, x)
```

it's a specific operation for NA?

Comment: What should be the output?

Answer (score 3):

`arrange` is used to order rows. You can pass variables names or expressions to it.

When you pass `is.na(df$x)` it returns :

```
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

`FALSE` is considered as 0 and `TRUE` as 1. Since you mention that you want to sort it in descending `TRUE` values come first and `FALSE` later, in case of tie rest of the values stay in the same order as they are present in the dataframe.

```
arrange(df, desc(is.na(x)))

#      x
#  <dbl>
#1    NA
#2     5
#3     2
```

Since 1st and 2nd value are the same (`FALSE`) it goes to the second variable which is passed to break the tie i.e `x`, where the values are sorted based on ascending order of values in `x`.

```
arrange(df, desc(is.na(x)), x)

#      x
#  <dbl>
#1    NA
#2     2
#3     5
```

Answer (score 2):

The `is.na()` function outputs a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` to represent if the corresponding vector element is a missing value. The `desc()` is helping the function `arrange()` to sort it descending (`TRUE` first, then `FALSE`), therefore it will likely appear to show the missing values at the top.

So no, it is not specific to the NA. It is there for the `arrange()`.